# How to fix "format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char **'" error

Tags: c, arrays, string, sockets

I am setting up a Client Socket system, and the code all will make but the part referencing server_response.  I am following a tutorial, but nobody else in the comments seemed to have this issue.  What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

I was following this tutorial about halfway through I encountered this bug, and the issue is not addressed in the comments or in the video.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtXEMwSG5-8

```
int network_socket;
network_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);  

//Address structure that holds access info for socket
struct sockaddr_in server_address;
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET; //specifies family or type of address, in this case an internet based one
server_address.sin_port = htons(13001); //specifies port
server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

//specifies socket, address point and the size of the address we are trying to connect to
//we save it as an int as if the connection is good it will return 0 if not it will be -1
int connection_status = connect(network_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
//checks for any error
if(connection_status == -1){
    printf("There was an error connecting to the remote socket\n\n\n");
    return 1;
}
//checks socket for any data size 250 chars long
char* server_response[300];
recv(network_socket, &server_response, sizeof(server_response), 0);

//prints data we get back
printf("server says:%s", server_response);
//closes socket
close(network_socket);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: I believe there’s a typo in your declaration of the variable `server_response`. That should probably be an array of `char`s rather than an array of `char *`s. Deleting the star should fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char* server_response[300];
//  ^
```

There should not be a `*` here. It's supposed to be an array of 300 chars. That way `sizeof(server_response)` in the following line will compute to 300 and `recv()` will read up to 300 bytes from the socket.